# Return statement is not working in python 3 , its does not return anything ,tried using yield but still the same

Tags: python, python-3.x, return

```
import random
def card():
    cards = [11, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10]
    return random.choice(cards)
card()
```

I did try using it in pycharm and repl.it but nothing seems to work

Comment: did you try `print(card())` ?? How are you checking the value?

Comment: It doesn't work because you aren't printing the value that `card` returns, just print it or store into a variable and then print it.

Comment: I copied and paste your code exactly as it is written in my OS terminal (not PyCharm) and it returns an output as expected, so your code is ok. So this is from PyCharm but can you precise how you run it in PyCharm ? Using the `Terminal` or `Python Console` in PyCharm ? Or using `Run` ? Because this is all different.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

That code It does returns a random list value. But if you want to see it on terminal you must type `print(card())` instead of just calling the `card()` method. Try that very same code on the interactive Python console. Otherwise you could have some issues (or missconfigurations) with your IDE.

Answer (score 1):

In your last line instead of calling the function. Try doing the following:

```
print(card())
```

It will work as the return statements replace the function

For example:
try storing the function in a variable like this:

```
a = card()
print(a)
```

Even this would work

Answer (score 0):

yes use print(card())
because a terminal wont  print anything if you just use the function()
but if you run your code using power-shell it will run as it is able to interpret function()

am using windows......
not sure if that's the case for Linux